# How to run word press theme on localhost in Ubuntu OS?

Tags: themes

I am new for wordpress and i am using Ubuntu OS on my computer I want to run a downloded theme on localhost how can i do that?

Comment: Do you have a server (PHP, Apache and MySQL) on your localhost? You didn't mention this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is two method for downloaded theme.

1. Then login as admin and navigate **Dashboard >> Appearance >> Themes**.
   Then click on Add new button then click on Upload theme button and browse download theme zip file like theme.zip. and click on install button.
   After installing theme click on activate theme button.

   **Note :** Your wordpress folder have **read/write** permission.
2. Paste your downloaded theme into **themes** directory located at **your_wordpress_folder/wp-content/** directory.
   Then login as admin and navigate **Dashboard >> Appearance >> Themes** and active your downloaded theme.

   View [How To Install A Theme On Localhost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tL06Cji0ClA)  tutorial for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to have a local web hosting environment. [Easy Engine](https://easyengine.io/) can install WordPress with  a single command. Then all you're left to do is to install the WordPress theme which can be done by going to the Dashboard >> Appearance. Click on Install then pick your theme of choice.